# What program is suitable for making scanned PDF files searchable?

Tags: pdf, scanner, search, ocr, tesseract

I would like to be able to scan paper documents to PDF files and make the text searchable. I believe the Tesseract program can assist this, but don't know how to begin, and don't know what would be the best program to use.

Is anybody making searchable PDF files successfully?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend `ocrmypdf`, see https://github.com/ocrmypdf/OCRmyPDF , also packaged for Ubuntu. You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt install ocrmypdf
```

You can use it as follows:

```
ocrmypdf -l eng infile.pdf outfile.pdf
```

The `ocrmypdf` call above is a simple one that specifies the document language as English (`-l eng`). There are many options in the [`man` page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/ocrmypdf.1.html); you might want to discover them as needed over time.